# Displaying images from a URL in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I'm trying to load user avatars from a S3 bucket where on making a `GET` request to `/uploads/resume/{user_uid}` a `URL` is returned with the image. This is how my request looks like

```
const getAvatar = async() => {
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + credentials);
    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: myHeaders,
      redirect: 'follow'
      };
     
      let response;

      try {
          response = await fetch (`${APIlink}/uploads/resume/${user_uid}`, requestOptions)
      } catch (err) {
          console.log("Failed");
          return;
      }
      const result = await response.text();
      setAvatarURL(result);
      console.log(avatarURL);

  };
```

Then I do

```
<img src={avatarURL}/>
```

in my render method to display the avatar of a user but nothing is displayed. On doing inspect element on the image tag I see the URL with an extra pair of double quotes something like this `<img src=""URL"">` avatarURL should be a string only then why is there an extra pair of quotes?

Doing `console.log(avatarURL);` gives me something like this "https://i**********-s3uploadbucket-119b74g6cdo0z.s=host***"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this :

```
<img src={avatarURL.replace(/['"]+/g, '')}/>  // to remove extra double quotes
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution but can you tell me why is this happening in the first place? where are the extra pair of quotes coming from?